# How would i check if a user has changed their nickname?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

i want to be able to change someones nickname to something every time they change it instantly. Is this possible with discord js or should i stick with the method of checking every time they send a message. Preferably i dont want the bot to be constantly checking

thanks in advance

edit: here is what i have now

```
bot.on('message', message => {
  if (message.author.id === config.____) {
    message.member.setNickname("_____")
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you done any research yet ? Can you link the article you've look up. Maybe what you've already tried.

Comment: @Nicolas edited the post with what i tried. I did some research, mostly more stack overflow and the discord js doc but couldnt find anything

Comment: This event fill fire when someone changes their nickname. https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberUpdate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use state **guildMemberUpdate**. Check if user have has nickname and nickname changet to 'somethink', then setNickname.

```
bot.on('guildMemberUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    if(newMember.nickname && oldMember.nickname !== newMember.nickname) {
        if(newMember.nickname === 'somethink') {
            newMember.setNickname('NickName')
        }
    }
 });
```